# Google Analytics for Apps - Tracking Search Terms within an app. Any ideas?

Tags: android, search, mobile, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

we are almost done with developing an app for our file hosting service. The app's main purpose is search engine within our hosted files, but Google Analytics Mobile does not have a feature similiar to Site Search Settings.

Does anyone have an idea on how to track the search terms?

Currently I only tought about pushing the search queries as screen names, for example: `mGaTracker.sendView("/search/SearchTerm")`
and collecting this data on one profile and filtering it on another. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
    private Tracker tracker;
// write code in on create of your activity

    tracker = GoogleAnalyticEntity.getInstance().getTracker();


//code for event
        tracker.sendEvent(ConstantLib.HmeScreen, ConstantLib.PreLoginScreen,


                "", 0l);
```

code for GoogleAnalyticEntity:-

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;

import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.EasyTracker;
import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.Tracker;

public class GoogleAnalyticEntity {

    public Tracker tracker;
    Context context;
    public static EasyTracker easytracker;
    private static GoogleAnalyticEntity instance;

    public static GoogleAnalyticEntity getInstance() {
        if (null == instance) {
            instance = new GoogleAnalyticEntity();

        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static void setInstance(GoogleAnalyticEntity instance) {
        GoogleAnalyticEntity.instance = instance;
    }

    public Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        EasyTracker.getInstance().setContext(context);

        this.context = context;
    }

    public void startTracker(Activity activity) {
        EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(activity);

    }

    public void StopTracker(Activity activity) {
        EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStop(activity);

    }

    public static EasyTracker getEasytracker() {
        if (easytracker == null) {
            easytracker = EasyTracker.getInstance();
        }
        return easytracker;
    }

    public Tracker getTracker() {
        if (tracker == null) {
            tracker = EasyTracker.getTracker();
        }
        return tracker;
    }

    public static void setEasytracker(EasyTracker easytracker) {
        GoogleAnalyticEntity.easytracker = easytracker;
    }

    public void setTracker(Tracker tracker) {
        this.tracker = tracker;
    }

    public void sentevent(Context mContext, String category, String label,
            String action, long val) {
        tracker.sendEvent(category, action, label, val);
    }
}
```

make analytics.xml in values folder:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!-- Replace placeholder ID with your tracking ID -->
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-4XXXXXXX-1</string>

    <!-- Enable Activity tracking -->
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

    <!-- Enable debug -->
    <bool name="ga_debug">true</bool>

    <!-- The screen names that will appear in your reporting -->
    <string name="com.test.screen.PreLoginActivity">PreLogin Screen</string>

  <!--
   The inverval of time after all the collected data
   should be sent to the server, in seconds.
    -->
    <integer name="ga_dispatchPeriod">30</integer>

</resources>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question